# How to align a button contained within a div central and bottom?

Tags: html, css, button, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have created three identical boxes (other than the description length contained within the p tag) containing an icon, title, description and button using the following HTML code:

```css
    .coursebutton {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #009ada;
    border: none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    padding: 9px;
    width: 100px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="col_one_third col_one_third_even">
     <div class="feature-box fbox-plain">
      <div class="fbox-icon">
       <img src="images/am-icon.png"/>
      </div>
      <h3>ADVERTISING AND MEDIA</h3>
      <p>Example example example example example example example example example example example example </p>
      <button class="coursebutton" onclick="window.location.href = 'courseinfo/am.html';"><span>Details </span></button>
     </div>
    </div>
```

How can I make the buttons always sit at the bottom of the box and in the center no matter how much text is within the p element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add relative position, a left of 50% and a translateX of -50% to your code. Regardless of text size, the button will always be centered.

You need the translate because the CSS left property is based on the size of the parent element and the transform property is based on the size of the target element. Using both you get the content completely centered in their parent.

```
.coursebutton {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: #009ada;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding: 9px;
  width: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/4aa1gwo6/)

**EDIT 1**

To get the buttons to be on the same level in different blocks, we need the blocks to be the same height. For this we can use something like javascript equalHeigh. Although for me the best option is to use flexbox.

https://jsfiddle.net/uugmvcvm/

Comment: This works perfectly for centering the button, thanks! However, if there is more text contained in one of the divs then the button in this div will sit lower than the other buttons. Is there a way to make the other buttons also sit this low?

Comment: In order for the buttons to be at the same height, you'll need the blocks to be the same size. Instead of using javascript matchHeight, I prefer to use flexbox: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uugmvcvm/)

Answer (score 0):

There is code for you.

Total:

- wrap the button by DIV
- add relative and padding to parent
- add absolute and text-align: center to button wrapper

[Codepen code](https://codepen.io/iMarkup/pen/godEEy)

```
.col_one_third {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  padding-bottom: 40px; // required
  position: relative;   // required
}
.button-wrapper {
  position: absolute;   // required
  bottom: 0;            // required
  left: 0;              // required
  text-align: center;   // required
  width: 100%;          // required
  padding: 5px;         // only styling
}
```